# sql query to calculate max loss on consecutive days in a row

Tags: sql-server

I have my stock market data in sql server database for my historical trades. Here is the table structure

Table Columns

- TradeDate
- StockName
- Quantity
- EntryPrice
- ExitPrice
- ProfitLoss

What I want to find out is the N consecutive days where I ended up in loss. Or putting it in other words maximum losing sequence that I ever encountered. I have data for 4 years.
    I have a sql which gives me daily profit loss but its too much data to find consecutive streak of losing days. Sharing that sql below

```
    select tradedate, sum(profitloss) as profitloss 
    from calls 
    where 
    group by TradeDate 
    order by ProfitLoss


   --Create table  
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calls](  
        [CallDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
        [StockName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,  
        [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,  
        [EntryPrice] [float] NOT NULL,  
        [ExitPrice] [float] NOT NULL,  
        [ProfitLoss] [float] NOT NULL  
    ) ON [PRIMARY]   


--Sample Data for a day  
TradeDate                StockName     Profitloss  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 HINDALCO    -999.6  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 CIPLA   -999.6  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 BPCL    -999  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 BANKBARODA  3256.25  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 TATASTEEL   3493.5  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 AMBUJACEM   6230.36  
2012-10-05 09:19:00.000 JINDALSTEL  7953.01
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Please tag the correct RDBMS (product and version)

Comment: what is the data of ProfitLoss column? can you provide some sample data and desired output? Also, it's better to provide the sample data DDL and DML statements so that the person answering your question can actually test that answer.

Comment: Hi, how can we get the value is Profit or Loss? is -ve is loss?

Comment: Yes..profit loss are number +ve when in profit and -ve numbers when in loss

Comment: It looks like `gaps-and-islands` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select tradedate, sum(profitloss) as profitloss 
from calls 
where 
group by TradeDate 
having sum(profitloss) < 0
order by tradedate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the test data or your flavor of SQL but this rough idea should work for you. Fit it to your data and SQL dialect.

Use 
`case when  ( sum(profitloss) over ( rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) * sum(profitloss) over ( rows between current_row and current_row) ) > 0 then 0 else 1 end as sign_change_marker`
And then `count(*) over ( rows from current row to following unbound reset when sign_change_marker = 1)` to calculate the streak length of win or loss going forward from each date